# Exporting a variable which is already being used inside an exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I am trying to initialize my mongodb in a separate file. I am writing the initialization inside a function and exporting the function. Now, I also want to export the db which is written inside that function.How can I do that?

I want to do something like this.

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import config from '../../config';
import logger from '../../logger';

const connectDB = async () => {
    const client = new MongoClient(config.dbUri, {
        userNewUrlParser: true,
         useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    try {
        await client.connect();
        const db = client.db('sample_mflix');
        logger.info('Connected to Database');
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
};
export default {
    connectDB,
    db,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I'd avoid the default export and do the following:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import config from '../../config';
import logger from '../../logger';

export let db;

export const connectDB = async () => {
    const client = new MongoClient(config.dbUri, {
        userNewUrlParser: true,
         useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    try {
        await client.connect();
        db = client.db('sample_mflix');
        logger.info('Connected to Database');
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
};
```

or if you wanted a nicer error

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import config from '../../config';
import logger from '../../logger';

let db;

export const getDB = () => {
  if (!db) {
    throw new Error("DB Not yet connected");
  }
  return db;
}

export const connectDB = async () => {
    const client = new MongoClient(config.dbUri, {
        userNewUrlParser: true,
         useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    try {
        await client.connect();
        db = client.db('sample_mflix');
        logger.info('Connected to Database');
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
};
```